# DatePicker - Get the date result based from the 1st picked date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Just wanna ask regarding on datepicker.

How can i get the Friday August 17, 2018 value if i choose the August 14, 2018? . Not only on that particular week but also everytime i choose a tuesday, it's automatically get the date value of each friday.

I already disabled monday, wed,thur,friday and those weekends just enabled the tuesday like this:

[Tuesday Enabled only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIXgS.jpg)

[image]

Once i choose 14, the To Date field will automatically get the value of Friday which is august 17, 2018 even it is disabled.

by the way, im using bootstrap-datepicker sandbox αlphα 1.6.4 version

[here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xxj4.jpg)

[image]

How can i do that? Thank you very much!!.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]. How is anyone supposed to help you without knowing what you are doing?

Comment: Make images visible by prepending a bang, e.g. `![][1]`.